# Ajax call from client to server in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call from client to server with some data and want to access the data on the server.

Client:

```
$('#searchName').blur(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "/getcontact",
          type:"GET",
          dataType:"json",
          data: {
            name: "Malek"
          },
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function( result ) {
            $( "#mob" ).value=result;
          }
        });       
    });
```

Server:

```
app.get("/getcontact",function(req,res){
console.log("===="+req.body.data+"====");
```

})

I am not able to get the value of name in req.body. If I console the req.body it is showing as [object Object] and when consoling req.body.data it is showing as undefined.

I have imported body-parser.

Comment: Change `$( "#mob" ).value=result;` to `$( "#mob" ).value(result);` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Could you stringify your body before `console.log`'ing it ? `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))`

Comment: Not working still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

req.body is meant to hold request payload and not query strings.

You should use req.query instead, since you are making a GET request and not a POST/PUT/PATCH request.

Comment: Its not working.An empty object  {} is being shown in the console.

Comment: Alright, I think you should get your data as "req.query.name", because I just realised you are sending a query string(GET request)

Comment: Not a problem, kindly upvote if this solves your issue.